C# http cookie not getting set in the browser
I'm trying to implement a JWT token authentication and I'm trying to store it in a HTTP cookie , but it is not getting set and i do not know why .
This is my cookie settings , inside the Log in function :
 [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Conturi>> LoginAccount([FromBody]LoginDto loginDto)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _userService.LoginAccountAsync(loginDto);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return Unauthorized(new {message = "Invalid credentials or account is not verified"});
                }
                
                var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Secure = false,
                    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2)
                };
                Response.Cookies.Append("JWTToken", loginDto.TokenProp, cookieOptions);
                return Ok(new { message = "Succesful login" });
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                return StatusCode(500, new { message = "An error occurred while processing your request." });
            }
        }

And this is what i m getting in my response headers:

But the cookie section is empty ( no cookie got set) .
Also this is my CORS setting in the backend:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowVueApp",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

And this is how i make the POST request from the frontend ( Vue.js)
async login(username,hPassword){
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${this.USER_API_BASE_URL}/login`, 
      {
          NumeProp : username ,
          ParolaProp : hPassword,
          TokenProp : ''
      },{withCredentials: true})
      if(response.status == 200){
        return 1
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during login', error.response.status);
      if(error.response.status === 500){
        return 0;
      }else if(error.response.status == 401){
        return -1;
      }
    }
    
  }

what am i missing here ?
UPDATE
Apparently , my Chrome somehow got bugged and even after i was refreshing page to see the token , it still was not displaying. I reopened it and now it worked .

You have cookie (Set-Cookie which is a JWtoken) in the response and getting a status of 200 OK.  Do not understand the issue.

It is not added in the cookie section of my browser , let me update .
